# Remove part of img path with JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<picture class="crop_auto">
<source media="(min-width: 413px)" data-srcset="https://images.thiswebsite.com/imagenes/hfm/20230104160859/crown-princess-mary-sustainable-silver-dress-new-year-2023/0-780-916/marygray2-z.jpg">
<source media="(min-width: 361px)" data-srcset="https://images.thiswebsite.com/imagenes/hfm/20230104160859/crown-princess-mary-sustainable-silver-dress-new-year-2023/0-780-916/marygray2-z.jpg?tx=w_412">
<img data-src="https://images.thiswebsite.com/imagenes/hfm/20230104160859/crown-princess-mary-sustainable-silver-dress-new-year-2023/0-780-916/marygray2-z.jpg?tx=w_360" alt="New Year's reception for the diplomatic corps at Christiansborg Palace" width="auto" height="auto" itemprop="url" src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/comunes/pixel-1x1.gif"></source></source></picture>
```

Which I am manipulating with the following - to turn the img data-src into src - but I need to remove this part of each image **?tx=w_360**

```
// Swap data-src for src
     $('img').each((index, element) => {
         let dataSrc;
       if ($(element).attr('data-src')) {
           dataSrc = $(element).attr('data-src');
       } else if ($(element).attr('src')) {
           dataSrc = $(element).attr('src');
       }

       if (dataSrc){
           // fix and decode the url if required
           if (dataSrc.startsWith('//')) dataSrc = `https:${dataSrc}`
           if (dataSrc.includes('%')) dataSrc = decodeURI(dataSrc);
           $(element).attr('src', dataSrc)
       }

       if ($(element).parents('figure').length === 1) $(element).unwrap()
     });
```

I can't seem to work out anyway to do it without breaking my code - any ideas?

Comment: would `imageUrl = imageUrl.split('.jpg')[0]` work for you. it basically removes anything substring after ".jpg"

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to remove any parameters at the end of the image url, I would use regex

```
dataSrc.replace(/\?.+/, '');
```